# How to get matrix rows by indexes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Assuming that we have a matrix X and a target column y as following:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.ones([10,2])
for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
    X[i][0] = i
y = [0,1,2,1,0,0,1,2,3,3]
```

I want to get rows of X depending on the value of y. From the small example above:

For y == 0, I want to get rows of X as:

```
[[0 1]
[4 1]
[5 1]]
```

For y == 3, I want to get rows of X as:

```
[[8 1]
[9 1]]
```

And so on. 
How can I solve this problem?

I also tried

```
print(X[y == 0][:])
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert ordinary python `array` to `numpy.ndarray`, as follow

```
Y=np.array(y)
print(X[Y == 0][:])
```

you will get:

```
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 4.  1.]
 [ 5.  1.]]
```